# layers.experimental.preprocessing.Rescaling

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

я не могу понять, как работает данный метод, мне нужно отмасштабировать(уменьшить) изображение в 2 раза и я не могу этого сделать.
Я так понимаю, что этот метод layers.experimental.preprocessing.Rescaling() уменьшает изображение? Есть ли ещё метод для уменьшения изображения в несколько раз?
tensorflow 2.7
keras 2.7
Посмотрел перевод документации и не понял, что это значит.
Перевод документации:
Чтобы изменить масштаб ввода в [0, 255]диапазоне, чтобы он находился в [0, 1]диапазоне, вы должны передать scale=1./255.

Чтобы изменить масштаб ввода в [0, 255]диапазоне, чтобы он находился в [-1, 1]диапазоне, вы должны передать scale=1./127.5, offset=-1.

Изменение масштаба применяется как во время обучения, так и во время вывода. Входные данные могут иметь целочисленный тип или тип с плавающей запятой, и по умолчанию слой будет выводить числа с плавающей запятой.

Примечание. Этот уровень безопасно использовать внутри tf.dataконвейера (независимо от того, какой сервер вы используете).

Аргументы

Scale : Float, масштаб, применяемый к входам.
offset : Float, смещение, применяемое к входам.
**kwargs : аргументы ключевых слов базового уровня, такие как nameи dtype.
Можете пожалуйста сказать, что такое "входы"? это изображения? заранее спасибо!

Comment: А может Вы слишком глубоко копаете? Уточните, для какой именно цели Вы масштабируете изображение? Я к чему, в некоторых препроцессах при подготовке blob-объекта есть поле с масштабом. К примеру, cv::dnn::blobFromImage(input_image, blob, 1./255., cv::Size(INPUT_WIDTH, INPUT_HEIGHT), imNetMean, true, true).

Answer (score 0):

Тот слой `Rescaling`, который вы хотите применить, изменяет не размер изображения, а **значения данных**. Например, у вас в данных есть значения в диапазоне от 0 до 255, а вы хотите получить значения диапазона от 0 до 1, тогда вы делаете `Rescaling` с коэффициентом 1/255 и получаете то, что хотели.

Если же вы хотите поменять именно **размер изображения**, то вам нужно использовать слой [keras.layers.Resizing](https://keras.io/api/layers/preprocessing_layers/image_preprocessing/resizing/). Задайте ему параметры - выходной размер изображения, тип сглаживания и т.д., и получите изменённый размер изображения.